# How to configure a redirection just for visitors coming from a specific address?

Tags: centos, apache-2.4, redirect, cloudflare

I've been handed a website using cloudflare workers to redirect a wordpress blog hosted in a subdomain to a subdirectory - for the most part it's a copypaste from this [cloudflare article](https://blog.cloudflare.com/subdomains-vs-subdirectories-improved-seo-part-2/) plus an if-check to redirect to the right locale - in other words:

- blog.companyname.com/en is masked as [www.companyname.com/blog](http://www.companyname.com/blog)
- blog.companyname.com/es is masked as [www.companyname.es/blog](http://www.companyname.es/blog)
- blog.companyname.com/de is masked as [www.companyname.de/blog](http://www.companyname.de/blog)

etc.

Of course they found out that crawlers and users could still access the original blog.companyname.com address, and asked me if I could somehow stop this host being directly accessible without causing issues for regular traffic.
Couldn't come up with a working solution using .htaccess trying to redirect everything excluding the Cloudflare IP block, and I'm wondering if i'm using the wrong approach (I'm a designer and wordpress developer by trade, definitely not a sysop/devop).

The blog is hosted on a managed solution using apache 2.4.6. Any suggestion is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Redirect, Change URLs or Redirect HTTP to HTTPS in Apache - Everything You Ever Wanted to Know About mod\_rewrite Rules but Were Afraid to Ask](https://serverfault.com/questions/214512/redirect-change-urls-or-redirect-http-to-https-in-apache-everything-you-ever)

Comment: Thanks for this guide! unfortunately it seems to be quite a generic explanation, there's very little regarding redirects based on matching incoming sources, except for a tiny bit on matching %{HTTP_REFERER} .